# How to modify CORS of an existing bucket in google cloud using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I create app engine using Terraform which creates a default bucket.
I would like to modify its CORS in the same terraform code.

When I use following code it tries to create a new bucket:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "app_engine_bucket" {
  name     = local.app_engine_default_bucket
  location = "US"
  cors {
    origin          = ["*"]
    method          = ["GET", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    response_header = ["Content-Type"]
    max_age_seconds = 3600
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to modify it using TF that you use to create the bucket.

Comment: I dont create this bucket. Its created by default when I create app engine

Comment: you could import the firebae storage (using cloud storage resource block) to your terraform state and set the settings via terraform

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added a comment that you're using Appengine, you'd use the app [configuration yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python) to specify your CORS settings.

Example:

```yaml
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mygame.uc.r.appspot.com
  # ...
```

If you wanted to modify buckets **not managed by AppEngine** you could specify the CORS configuration in the [configuration for the bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket) as Marcin mentioned in the comments.

example:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "static-site" {
  name          = "image-store.com"
  location      = "EU"
  force_destroy = true

  uniform_bucket_level_access = true

  website {
    main_page_suffix = "index.html"
    not_found_page   = "404.html"
  }
  cors {
    origin          = ["http://image-store.com"]
    method          = ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"]
    response_header = ["*"]
    max_age_seconds = 3600
  }
}
```